# range end xldown not working

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to select a row and then CtrlShift end down, but without .SELECT etc...

```
        Set rng = wsDATA.Range("A8").EntireRow
        Set rng = Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
```

but I get an `Application Defined or Object Defined Error` on the second line.  Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I'm constantly reminded, is to re-read code when you encounter problems and make sure everything is qualified.

In this case, I should have used my worksheet object `wsDATA` before the .range

```
        Set rng = wsDATA.Range("A8:A8").EntireRow
        Set rng = wsDATA.Range(rng, rng.End(xlDown))
```